# jquery .grep is not removing array element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var numbers = ['sachin', 'raaj', 'rahul', 'mahesh', 'sandip'];
    $('#btn').click(function ()
```

> { 
>               var c = $("#ad_list option:selected").text();

```
        numbers = jQuery.grep(numbers, function (value) {
            return value != c;
        }); >
    });
    var option = '';
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        option += '<option value="' + i + '">' + numbers[i] + '</option>'; >
    }
    $('#ad_list').append(option);
});
```

below is html code dropdownlist  showing element in array

```
<label>ADD:</label>               
<select name="ADD_list" id="ad_list"></select>        
<input type="submit"  id="btn" />
```

Comment: Don't use quotation markup for code, use the code markup `{}`.

Comment: Why would you name an array of names "numbers"??

Comment: It seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/gdnty/

Comment: @Barmar i have made some changes on jsfiddle can you help me out

Comment: Please explain the problem more clearly. And give a link to your fiddle that demonstrates it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gdnty/2/

Comment: i updated your fiddle. you need to update your option list after you run `jQuery.grep`. try this http://jsfiddle.net/gdnty/3/

Comment: is it solving your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your option after removing the selected element:

```
function updateOption(numbers) {
    $("#ad_list").empty();
    var option = '';
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        option += '<option value="' + i + '">' + numbers[i] + '</option>';
    }
    $('#ad_list').append(option);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var numbers = ['sachin', 'raaj', 'rahul', 'mahesh', 'sandip'];
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        var c = $("#ad_list option:selected").text();
        numbers = jQuery.grep(numbers, function (value) {
            return value != c;
        });
        updateOption(numbers);
    });
    updateOption(numbers);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KwSgL/)**